# How to assign symlinks to serial devices from usb-to-serial device CP2105?

Tags: linux, udev, ttyusb

I have board with CP2105. It is usb-to-serial bridge with two uart interfaces on one usb port. I've read some guides, and documentation of UDEV, but I'm stuck on creating symlinks for them. I want them to have serial ID in name. The problem is that it does not work, even with simple rules.

My rule, that should do what I want:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", \
    ATTR{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTR{idProduct}=="ea70",
    ENV{ID_MODEL}=="CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller", \
    SYMLINK+="CP2105$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}-$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}"
```

Simpler attempt, that should add two symlinks with different number at the end:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTR{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTR{idProduct}=="ea70", SYMLINK+="CP2105%n"
```

I also have one rule, that works, but does something else (prevents some other driver from writing to this device):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTR{idProduct}=="ea70", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

My udevadm info output for first device:

```
udevadm info -q all /dev/ttyUSB0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
N: ttyUSB0
S: serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0087144E-if00-port0
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3:1.0-port0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3:1.0-port0 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0087144E-if00-port0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyUSB0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=CP2105\x20Dual\x20USB\x20to\x20UART\x20Bridge\x20Controller
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=CP210x UART Bridge
E: ID_MODEL_ID=ea70
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_3_1_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Serial bus controller
E: ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=XHCI
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=USB controller
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0087144E
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0087144E
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cp210x
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Silicon_Labs
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Silicon\x20Labs
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=10c4
E: MAJOR=188
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5571337818
```

And the second one:

```
udevadm info -q all /dev/ttyUSB1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1
N: ttyUSB1
S: serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0087144E-if01-port0
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3:1.1-port0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3:1.1-port0 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0087144E-if01-port0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyUSB1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.3/3-5.3:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=CP2105\x20Dual\x20USB\x20to\x20UART\x20Bridge\x20Controller
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=CP210x UART Bridge
E: ID_MODEL_ID=ea70
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.3:1.1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_3_1_1
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Serial bus controller
E: ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=XHCI
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=USB controller
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0087144E
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0087144E
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cp210x
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
E: ID_VENDOR=Silicon_Labs
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Silicon\x20Labs
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=10c4
E: MAJOR=188
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5570324399
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, that I had to change two things. First I had to make number from filename with my rules higher (I changed it from 52 to 70). Second, I noticed, that `ATTR{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTR{idProduct}=="ea70"` didn't work, as there was no attributes avaliable for checking for subsysem tty. I changed it to proper environmental variables, and ended with this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", \
    ENV{ID_MODEL}=="CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller", \
    ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="10c4", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="ea70", \
    SYMLINK+="ttyCP2105-$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}-$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}"
```